# In golang, How can I override the embedded struct's method

Tags: go, polymorphism, overriding, proxy-classes

Code [here](http://play.golang.org/p/lzWKavxgzr)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    t16()
}

type Base struct {
    val int
}
func (b *Base)Set(i int) {
    b.val = i
}
type Sub struct {
    Base
    changed bool
}

func (b *Sub)Set(i int) {
    b.val = i
    b.changed = true
}
func t16() {
    s := &Sub{}
    s.Base.Set(1)
    var b *Base = &s.Base
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", b)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", s)
}
```

I want to make Sub act as Base, but when I call Set, for Sub it will mark the changed.I know there is no polymorphism or proxy in golang, but is there any way to do this, and not effect the Base?

**UPDATED**

I hope when I call Base.Set it will mark the change, for user, they don't know they actually use the Sub, so I can monitor the Base behave.

```
func t16() {
    s := &Sub{}
    var b *Base = &s.Base
    b.Set(10)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", b)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", s)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

By having `Sub` embed `Base` it automatically has all of `Base`'s fields and functions made available as top level members of `Sub`. This means you can directly call `s.val`, and you *would* be able to call `s.Set` to invoke the base function **except** for the fact that `Sub` implemented its own `Set` method which *hides* the Base one.

When you call `s.Base.Set()` in your example you are bypassing `Sub.Set()` and directly calling `Base.Set()`.

To fix it in your case is as simple as calling `s.Set()` instead of `s.Base.Set()`.

This works for me:

```
func (b *Sub)Set(i int) {
    b.Base.Set(i)
    b.changed = true
}
func t16() {
    s := &Sub{}
    s.Set(1)
    var b *Base = &s.Base
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", b)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", s)
}
```

[Play link](http://play.golang.org/p/yjIMAFXjy-)

Notice that `Sub.Set()` can invoke the embedded structs method as well, which feels a lot like the `super()` type inheritance that other oo languages provide.

Comment: If that is the case, then you are correct, interfaces are the way to go. Go has no `is-a` type inheritance.